# what does I mean in c++?

Tags: c++, arguments, uml

I have a method, where `x` is a class and in the *UML*, for a different class (that uses *class x*), a method is written as:

```
+setX(x I &)
```

---

What does the `I` in the argument mean? or is it just a typo?

Comment: This looks like some other language than C++, perhaps objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a poorly formatted UML entry regarding a public function named `setX` taking a *reference* to an instance of `x`, and naming that *reference* `I`.

---

I'm guessing the author meant to write `+setX(INOUT I : x)` but got the syntax of the implementation language (in this case *c++*) mixed up with the *Unified Modeling Language*.

`INOUT I : x` will make `setX` accept a variable used for both input and output of type `x`, and name this parameter `I`.

---

<sup>*Note:* `setX(x I&)` is not legal *c++*, but `setX(x& I)` is.</sup>

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo then because we're definitely working with c++